# how to remove unused code from r.java

Tags: android

I got an error in logcat:

> recyclerview: No adapter attached; skipping layout"

But I did not use `recyclerview` in my project, when I find `recyclerview` in my complete project it will be generated in r.java file about 51 times but I do not use in my project as I clean and rebuild my project but nothing happens.

What's going on?

Comment: Just because you do not use it in your own code does not mean that your *app* does not use it, as other libraries that you use might depend upon it. Beyond that, `R.java` holds pointers to resources, not pointers to Java classes. Unused code in `R.java` will be removed on `release` builds if you set up ProGuard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CommonsWare is right "Just because you do not use it in your own code does not mean that your app does not use it, as other libraries that you use might depend upon it" you must have some libraries added in your code using Recyclerview. Just to check where it is used in your code you can do one thing

Navigate to `RecyclerView` class then try to `Find Usages` you will get the logs where it is used.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help i will find recylerview through this.